# Why aren't my input validations preventing empty values?

Tags: php, mysql

Every time I click add when I have no value for Make, Model or Mileage I keep getting the same error and I don't know how to fix it. It runs fine if I insert the correct information, but it won't show my validations.

Here is the code.

Here is the error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
> 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'year' at row 1 in
> C:\MAMP\htdocs\course_2_week2\autos.php:30 Stack trace: #0
> C:\MAMP\htdocs\course_2_week2\autos.php(30):
> PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown
> inC:\MAMP\htdocs\course_2_week2\autos.phpon line30

````
<?php 

require_once "pdo.php";

$failure = false;  // If we have no POST data
$failure2 = false;  // If we have no POST data for make

// Demand a GET parameter
if ( ! isset($_GET['email']) || strlen($_GET['email']) < 1  ) {
    die('Email parameter missing');
}

if ( isset($_POST['make']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['mileage']) && isset($_POST['add'])) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO autos (make, year, mileage) 
            VALUES (:make, :year, :mileage)";
    echo("<pre>\n".$sql."\n</pre>\n");

        // Validation checks
        if ( ! (is_numeric($_POST['mileage']) || is_numeric($_POST['year'])) ) {
            $failure = 'Mileage and year must be numeric';
        } if ( strlen($_POST['make']) < 1) {
            $failure2 = 'Make is required';  // If we have no POST data for make
        } 

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':make' => $_POST['make'],
        ':year' => $_POST['year'],
        ':mileage' => $_POST['mileage'])
        );

} 

// If the user requested logout go back to index.php
if ( isset($_POST['logout']) ) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT make, year, mileage FROM autos");
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <?php require_once "bootstrap.php"; ?>
    <title>Zaccharie Charvolin's Login Page</title>
    
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" >
    
    <h2>Please Login</h2>
    
    <form method="post">
        <p>Make:
        <input type="text" size="40" name="make"></p>
        <p>Year:
        <input type="text" size="40" name="year"></p>
        <p>Mileage:
        <input type="text" size="40" name="mileage"></p>
        <input type="submit" size="40" value="Add" name="add"></p>
        <input type="submit" size="40" name="logout" value="Log out" ></p>
    </form>
    
    <h2>Automobiles</h2>
    
<?php
    
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<ul><li>";
                
        echo($row['year'].' ');
        
        echo($row['make'].' / ');

        echo($row['mileage']);

        echo("</li></ul>\n");
}
?>
    
</div>

</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: What part of error message exactly is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the SQL even when the validation fails. You should check if any of the failure variables are set and skip it.

```
if (!$failure && !$failure2) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':make' => $_POST['make'],
        ':year' => $_POST['year'],
        ':mileage' => $_POST['mileage'])
    );
}
```

To avoid having lots of `$failureX` variables, I suggest you use an array instead of separate variables. Then you can just check if the array is empty:

```
if (empty($failures)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's greatly appreciated. I also need to show errors when the make is empty and the year and mileage have no integers in them. And I can't figure out how to make errors show up. It's probably because I'm so new at this lol.

Comment: nvm figured it out